# TFS - Specialized Group has no access to Work Items

Tags: tfs, group-membership

I created a tfs group that would work on a specific project located in a collection.  Now we're using work items to track bugs etc, but that group doesn't have access to those work items via the Team Web Access portal.  I don't want this group to have access to all the projects in the collection, just the one they are working on.    But i need them to be able to access work items that come up.

Currently when they access the Team Web Access portal, they get message indicating there are no accessible team projects in this team project collection.

if they can access their code in the collection already, how come they can't see the work items, and how can i change that, but still limit what they see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found what i was looking for after some time.  for the benefit of the community here is where that hidden security setting is done.

For the new group, i needed to go under Team/Team Project Settings/Area and Iterations!!!!

Yes, this silly place to but a SECURITY button.  If you go in there, click the security button on the bottom of the dialog, you will then see ALL the WORK ITEM related permissions.

- EDIT work items in this node;
- Manage Test plans;
- View this node;
- View work items in this node.

I needed to check all of these to ALLOW.

Again, seems like a stupid place to put these settings, than with all the other security settings via  TEAM Project Settings.  I hope they had a good reason for that.

Comment: "For the new group, i needed to go under Team/Team Project Settings/Area and Iterations!!!!" This is the key information

Comment: @Mehrdad did you figure out how to limit access to source code?

Answer (score 0):

They will need the `View collection-level details` permission added to their group (at the collection level). By default, the `Project Collection Valid Users` group has these permissions, so you can just add your group as a member of the valid users group.

Comment: hmm that group is a Member of "Project Collection of Valid Users" ... and the "Valid Users" group has that setting set.

Comment: What are the specific permissions you have for that group at the project and collection level? As well as any groups they are members of?

Comment: The default Contributors group which has all the other users don't have a problem.  if i move the 'group X' under the default Contributors group, they all of a sudden have access.   I made sure the group x contributors have same as contributors. and each individually under the Valid Users.  but that doesn't work..     if i look under each contributor group i see they are members of the "project collection of valid users".

Comment: What permissions does the custom group have?

Comment: the same for each... Create test runs, delete test runs, manage test configs, manage test environments, view project-level info, view test runs.    Both groups have these checked.    And since they are both members of the Project Collection of Valid Users, i haven't changed any security settings at the collection level.